# material-ui: input alters the tabs' this.state.value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material-UI for a React app. I am using the controllable `Tabs` and `Tab` components. In the recommended setup, `this.state.value` is used to determine which tab is open. When I enter text in an `input` field inside a tab, it alters  `this.state.value` to a `SyntheticEvent`. This happens even if the input box is in a separate component. As a result, the current tab gets closed. I would like to prevent the input text from closing the current tab. Suggestions please?

```
var React = require('react');
var Tabs = require('material-ui/lib/tabs/tabs');
var Tab = require('material-ui/lib/tabs/tab');

module.exports = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            value: 'newGoal'
        };
    },
    handleChange(value) {
        this.setState({
            value: value
        });
    },
    render() {
        console.log("this.state.value at TABS:", this.state.value);
        return (
            <Tabs
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            >
                <Tab label="New Goal" value="newGoal" >
                    <input></input>
                </Tab>
                <Tab label="Existing Goal" value="existingGoal">
                </Tab>
            </Tabs>
        )
    }
});
```

Comment: It sounds like you're using the same `onChange` function for your input that you're using for your tabs. Can you show the input code please?

Comment: There is no input code. It's just a plain html 5 tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were hit by [this issue](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/1595). One easy way to fix it is to do a type check in handleChange like -

```
handleChange(value) {
    if (typeof value != "string"){
        return;
    }
    this.setState({
        value: value
    });
},
```